# How can I check if a string has personalized errors?

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a program where I input a name and a surname and the code checks if the name is invalid (list of invalidiations below). If it has any invalidations, it asks me to say the name again and presents me a list of all the invalidations. 
Invalidations list (I'll show the code version too):
- The name has digits
- The name has symbols
- The name has no spaces
- It has more then one space
- One of the names is either too short or too long
- The first letter of the name is a space
- The last letter of the name is a space

I can't use exceptions here, because these are not code erros. I've made it with Ifs, but it got to a point where there a simply lots of Ifs for it to be viable.

```py
def has_digits(name):
    digits = any(c.isdigit() for c in name)
    if digits == True:
        return True
        print("Your name has digits.")
    else:
        return False


def has_symbols(name):
    symbols = any(not c.isalnum() and not c.isspace() for c in name)
    if symbols == True:
        return True
        print("Your name has symbols.")
    else:
        return False


def has_no_spaces(name):
    spaces = any(c.isspace() for c in name)
    if not spaces == True:
        return True
        print("You only gave me a name.")
    else:
        return False


def many_spaces(name):
    m_s = name.count(' ') > 1
    if m_s == True:
        return True
        print("Your name has more than one space.")
    else:
        return False


def unrealistic_length(name, surname):
    length= (float(len(name)) < 3 or float(len(name)) > 12) or float(len(surname)) < 5 or float(len(surname) > 15)
    if length == True:
        return True
        print("Your name has an unrealistic size.")
    else:
        return False


def first_space(name):
    f_s = name[0] == " "
    if f_s == True:
        return True
        print("The first letter of your name is a space.")
    else:
        return False


def last_space(name):
    l_s = name[-1] == " "
    if l_s == True:
        return True
        print("The last letter of your name is a space.")
    else:
        return False


name = "bruh browski"
namesplit = name.split(" ")
name1 = namesplit[0]
name2 = namesplit[1]

print(has_digits(name))
print(has_symbols(name))
print(has_no_spaces(name))
print(many_spaces(name))
print(unrealistic_length(name1, name2))
print(first_space(name))
print(last_space(name))
```

Maybe the prints shouldn't be in the defs themselves. I don't know. I'm almost sure doing a for loop is the way to go, but I just can't imagine how to do it.

Result:

```
False
False
False
False
False
False
False
```

Comment: My first impression is that I expect a function to return `True` if the input is good/acceptable and not the other way around. Personally, I would modify the definitions to reflect this but.... that's just me nit-picking the design...sorry. You could have one master verifying function that checks each of your individual verifications. The generator solution from the answer below could go inside your master verifying function

Comment: You're right, @SyntaxVoid. I'll modify it. How can I make that master verifying function? I'm still new 

Comment: Have you thought about using regular expressions?

Answer (score 3):

The methods you've used to define exactly what counts as each "invalidation" will have to stay, unless you can replace them with something else that does the same thing. But you can check all of those conditions at once using a generator expression:

```
if any(is_invalid(name) for is_invalid in [
        has_digits, has_symbols, has_no_spaces, many_spaces, unrealistic_length, first_name, last_name
        ]):
    # then this string is invalid
# otherwise, all of those returned false, meaning the string is valid.
```

You can then use that condition to determine when to stop asking the user, or however else you need to.

If you wanted to not individually define all those functions, you could also maybe use lambdas to do the same thing.

---

As a sidenote, before actually using this in production for checking the validity of names, I advise having a look at the list of [Falsehoods Programmers Believe about Names](https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/). It's a fun read even if it's not relevant to your use case, though.

Comment: Thank you!! I'll try to work with it! Yes, it was a fun read. But my program is destined to portuguese names (just me, actually), so I guess many of the assumptions are correct

Answer (score 1):

You could have a single function which calls all of your other functions and handles it appropriately.

```py
def master_verify(name):
    # Put all your verify functions in the list below.
    verify_funcs = [has_digits, has_symbols, has_no_spaces, many_spaces,
                    unrealistic_length, first_space, last_space]
    # It will return True if any your functions return True. In this case,
    # returning True means the name is invalid (matching your other 
    # function design). Returning False means the name is valid.
    return any(is_invalid(name) for is_invalid in verify_funcs)
```

Since you mentioned you want the program to find any name errors and ask the user to try again, we can write a loop to handle this.

```py
def get_name():
    while True:
        # Loop until you get a good name
        name = input("Enter your name: ").strip()
        if master_verify(name): 
            # Remember, if True this means invalid
            print("Invalid name. Try again.")
            continue   # continue jumps to the top of a loop, skipping everything else.
        return name # Will only get here if the name is valid.
```

I also suggest you should do the name and surname split inside your `unrealistic_length` function.

Then, all you need to do is

```py
name = get_name()

# All of the validation has already happened.
print(f"The correct and validated name is: {name}")
```

Last but not least, anything in a function after a `return` is unreachable. So a lot of your `print`s will never happen. Put the `print` statements before your return.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your answer. But I also mentioned that I want the code to present me a list of errors. But I already managed to do it. I'll post it here. Thanks anyways!

Answer (score 0):

Alright. I've managed to do it by myself. I still fill there's a better way to do it, but this is the way I found.

```py
errors_list = []
print("Hi. Tell me your first and last name.")
def choose_name(name):
    global fname
    global sname
    fname = ""
    sname = ""

    global errors_list

    try:
        no_letters = any(c.isalpha() for c in name)
        no_spaces = name.count(" ") == 0
        digits = any(c.isdigit() for c in name)
        symbols = any(not c.isalnum() and not c.isspace() for c in name)
        many_spaces = name.count(" ") > 1
        first_space = name[0] == " "
        last_space = name[-1] == " "

        if no_letters == False:
            errors_list.append("It has no letters")

        if no_spaces == True:
            errors_list.append("It has no spaces")
        else:
            namesplit = name.split(" ")
            fname = namesplit[0]
            sname = namesplit[1]
            pass

        if fname and sname is not "":
            bad_length = (float(len(fname)) < 3 or float(len(fname)) > 12) or float(len(sname)) < 4 or float(len(sname) > 15)
            if bad_length == True:
                errors_list.append("One of your names has an unrealistic size")
                pass
        else:
            bad_length = (float(len(name)) < 3 or float(len(name)) > 12)
            if bad_length == True:
                errors_list.append("It has an unrealistic size")
                pass

        if digits == True:
            errors_list.append("It has digits")
            pass

        if symbols == True:
            errors_list.append("It has symbols")
            pass

        if many_spaces == True:
            errors_list.append("It has more than one space")
            pass

        if first_space == True:
            errors_list.append("The first letter is a space")
            pass

        if last_space == True:
            errors_list.append("The last letter is a space")
            pass
    except IndexError:
        print("You must write something. Try again.")
        name = input("My name is ").title()
        choose_name(name)

name = input("My name is ").title()
choose_name(name)

while True:
    if len(errors_list) != 0:
        print("Your name has these errors:")
        for i in errors_list:
                print("     " + str(errors_list.index(i) + 1) + "- " + i + ".")
        print("Try again.")
        errors_list.clear()
        name = input("My name is ").title()
        choose_name(name)
    else:
        print("Nice to meet you, " + fname + " " + sname + ".")
        break
```

Result when I type the name '----... '

```
Hi. Tell me your first and last name.
My name is ----...    
Your name has these errors:
     1- It has no letters.
     2- It has symbols.
     3- It has more than one space.
     4- The last letter is a space.
Try again.
My name is
```